# UNMutableNotificationContent - Change the default App Icon

Tags: swift

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the default App icon that is used within UNMutableNotificationContent to a different image dynamically while using the app?

Is there a private method that will do this?

Hopefully this is a easy, question to answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. There is no reference on Apple's website about this, and the only way if I recall correctly requires user interaction  and only works when the app is foregrounded. The user will be shown with an alert when the icon is changed, saying:

**You changed the app icon for "*YourApp*".**

So, I don't think this is currently possible. Though I'd love to see that come in new software releases.

Comment: Okay. Maybe it's something we'll see today @ DubDub.  Thanks for replying back to me.